# LLDB API: Why SBValue::Cast is deprecated and how to replace it with CreateValueFromExpression?

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

SBValue::Cast marked as deprecated in LLDB headers:

```
// Deprecated - use the expression evaluator to perform type casting
lldb::SBValue Cast(lldb::SBType type);
```

But I can't understand how to replace it with expression evaluation.

Suppose I have:

```
auto casted_val = my_value.Cast(my_type);
```

What would be equivalent expression, taking into account that both value and type can be out of current scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast is deprecated because it isn't a real C++ cast.  In particular if you cast from a pointer to a base class to one to it's parent class, `SBValue::Cast` doesn't do the work to take into account the position of the base class in it's parent and offset the pointer accordingly.  All it does is extract the address of the original value object and cast THAT to the new type.  Unfortunately, various uses of Cast rely on this simplistic cast behavior, to we can't just make it right.

For C & ObjC types, this sort of "Cast" is not going to cause any problems.  For C++ classes with single inheritance, it is also always correct.  It will fail for when casting from a base class to a parent that multiply inherits from several classes (and the base isn't the first class in the inheritance hierarchy.)

Any of the "evaluate expression" calls with a proper cast expression should work, clang will get the offsetting right in the code it generates.  So for instance:

```
casted_value = frame.EvaluateExpression("(MyType *) var_to_cast");
```

`SBFrame::EvaluateExpression` will search for types & globally visible objects moving outward from the current scope.  So finding variables & types from other contexts should only be problem if there are multiple incompatible types/variables that are visible at the same level.

Another way to work around this is to hand define the type you want.  In lldb, if you write an expression that defines a type, and give the type a name beginning with a $, that type will be available in future expression evaluation. Depending on how complex your hidden type is, you may be able to copy the type definition into an lldb convenience type, and use that.

The real solution to this is to add some syntax to the expression parser (equivalent to gdb's "::") to specify the context for the symbol name. But that bit of work hasn't been done yet.  Or, of course, add a real C++ aware SBValue::Cast.

Comment: But what if MyType is in another nested scope, and thus not visible without global search?

Comment: First off, unless you are printing types where the base is offset in the parent, Cast should be fine.  The API is not going away until we call version 2.0 of the SB API's.  The code warning is more to say that this "Cast" method isn't a Cast really...

Comment: Note, if you write an expression that defines a type, and give the type a name beginning with a $, that type will be available in future expression evaluation.  Depending on how complex your hidden type is, you may be able to copy the type definition into an lldb convenience type, and use that.  That will be visible everywhere.

Comment: The real solution to this is to add some syntax to the expression parser (equivalent to gdb's "::") to specify the context for the symbol name.  But that bit of work hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Thanks. If you can put those comments to answer I will mark it as accepted. I think they are too valuable to be hidden in comments.